# Newtonsoft.Json problem getting nested object values

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a problem getting a nested object after JObject.Parse.

With this:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
  BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
       RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
       ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
string CheckRequiredVersion(string PROGRAM, string ptotal_current, string ptotal_required, string pNotification);
```

and

```
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { result = false, ptotal_required = total_required, pNotification = pNotification });
```

I have this JSON string:

{
    "CheckRequiredVersionResult": "{\"result\":false,\"ptotal_required\":999999,\"pNotification\":\"\"}"
}

Now when I do JObject.Parse from that string only first {} is actually an object second is treated as a string.

Now, is there a way to treat value from CheckRequiredVersionResult as an object too? So I can access its value with:

```
ptotal_required = j["CheckRequiredVersionResultResult"]["ptotal_required"].ToString();
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've realized my mistake, we can't return any anonymous type from any method - we must use a named type.

So I had to add a class to the model:

```
  public class CheckRequiredVersionClass
  {
    public bool result { get; set; }
    public int ptotal_required { get; set; }
    public string pNotification { get; set; }
  }
```

and to change the way to return it (as a CheckRequiredVersionClass)

```
      return new CheckRequiredVersionClass { result = false, ptotal_required = total_required, pNotification = pNotification };
```

Now I am getting the results correctly, like a nested object:

{
  "CheckRequiredVersionResult": {
    "pNotification": "",
    "ptotal_required": 999999,
    "result": false
  }
}

Comment: Another solution is with [tuples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples). the result is almost the same)